# Removing query conditions from a Laravel Nova metric that uses refreshWhenFiltersChange()

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-nova

I have a Nova v4 metric that does this calculation to get related data from another table to be shown in the same resource view.

```
class ReportOrderSum extends Value
{
    public function __construct(protected string $column, $component = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($component);
    }

    public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        $query = Order::where('status', 'completed');

        return $this
            ->sum($request, $query, $this->column)
            ->transform(fn($value) => $value / 100)
            ->format([
                'thousandSeparated' => true,
                'mantissa'          => 2,
            ])
            ->dollars();
    }
}
```

This is used in the `Reports` resource to get related data from the orders table.

It is added to the `Reports` resource like this:

```
public function cards(NovaRequest $request)
{
    return [
        Metrics\ReportOrderSum::make('fees')
            ->defaultRange('ALL')
            ->width('1/4')
            ->refreshWhenFiltersChange(),
    ];
}
```

However, the reports also have filters that use columns not on the orders table, so if I apply any filters, they are not always guaranteed to be compatible with the orders query so I get errors.

How do I remove the filter based query conditions for this metric that are incompatible?